# Selenium find element with variable value

Tags: python, selenium

i want to click an element with a value, which will be inserted by user. I tried this:

```
def transition(action, value=none):
    if (action=='next_page'):
        button = driver.find_element_by_link_text('"value"')
        button.click()

  transition('next_page', value='car1')
```

The problem is that 'car1' value isn't inserted. What can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What your code does, is actually calling the `find_element` function with the string *"value"*, as you wrote it in quotation marks, making it a **string literal**

```
button = driver.find_element_by_link_text('"value"')
```

What you want to do is insert the name of the variable *value* without any "double" or 'single' quotation marks, like so.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_link_text(value)
```

As you are having a hard time dealing with such simple python syntax, I recommend you first learn the bare basics of the language before trying to write applications with it. There are a lot of free resources out there.
I can recommend [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) as a website with text and interactive examples or if you are more of the video type of learner, I can recommend the course by [freeCodeCamp.org](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw) or a video series by [Tech With Tim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFrLs22MDAw&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-mFu00qxl0a67RhjjZj3jXm&index=1). Though the last one didn't age really well.